# Is there a security changelog for Canonical snap packages?

Tags: security, snap, canonical

Lets take [CVE-2021-3448](https://ubuntu.com/security/cve?package=dnsmasq) as an example.

It's easy to see when the deb package got the backported fix, and what package is installed on the server.

But the same package in a snap:

```
/snap/lxd/21468/bin/dnsmasq --version
Dnsmasq version 2.80 .....
```

```
snap list
lxd     4.18      21468  latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
```

Do you know if there is a way to see if that CVE is backported to 2.80 in the Canonical `lxd` snap somewhere?
Perhaps I am missing some really easy way to get this information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the deb update information, you're halfway there.

1. Since LXD is distributed as a snap, you should always be running the latest version *for your channel* automatically. In this example, LXD 4.0.7 is in the *stable* channel, and installed on a 20.04 server:

   ```
   $ snap list lxd
   Name  Version  Rev    Tracking      Publisher   Notes
   lxd   4.0.7    21029  4.0/stable/…  canonical✓  -
   ```
2. Next, let's head over to https://launchpad.net/lxd/+snaps and find that stable version...

   [image]

   ...aha. Here it is: [https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-lxc/+snap/lxd-4.0-candidate](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-lxc/+snap/lxd-4.0-candidate) . You can see the build date --which is after the CVE (good)-- and a link to the build log for each architecture.

   [image]
3. Let's take a closer look at that build log. This particular snap is built, under the hood, from debs! Let's zero in on the exact deb package used for the build.

   - The URL for the buildlog is https://launchpadlibrarian.net/549848217/buildlog_snap_ubuntu_bionic_arm64_lxd-4.0-candidate_BUILDING.txt.gz . The word '`_bionic_`' in there shows us that the LXD snap is built from 18.04 (Bionic) packages; that it's running on a 20.04 system isn't relevant.
   - A quick grep gives us the actual dnsmasq deb package used: `Get:1 dnsmasq-base_2.79-1ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb [279 kB]`

   (**Wait a second**....It's the `dnsmasq-base` package instead of the `dnsmasq` package. No `dnsmasq` package suggests that the CVE may-or-may-not apply after all. However, let's overlook that and keep going for the final step)
4. Finally, let's look at the [Ubuntu Security Team CVE tracker](https://ubuntu.com/security/cve) to make sure that the package is properly fixed. Were the LXD snap using `dnsmasq` instead of `dnsmasq-base`, you can see that the build used a properly patched version (highlighted).

   - Remember that we're looking for the 18.04 (Bionic) package, since that's what was used to build the Snap.

   [image]

Comment: May you get many upvotes :) 2 thumbs up

Comment: Marked as a correct answer. 
A huge thanks for your time!